# How do I display my saved quantities?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my store I have an orders table that captures the orders made by each customer. I want to be able to show the user what quantity of an item they have in their cart. Here is my orders model:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Customer { get; set; }
    public string ShirtCause {get; set;}
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public ShirtSize ShirtSize { get; set; }         
    public ShirtQuantity ShirtQuantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public string ShirtYear { get; set; }
    public int OrderNum { get; set; }
    public bool? OrderCompleted { get; set; }
    public bool? RecievedShirt { get; set; }
}
```

Using code first `ShirtQuantity` is created in a table and is reflected in the column `ShirtQuantity_Id`. For reference purposes, here is my quantity model:

```
public class ShirtQuantity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

The cart should be output and enumerated in the action with:

```
return View(db.Orders.ToList());
```

All except for the Quantity_Id will list when calling

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.Order>
```

in the view. How do I get these quantities to list? I have tried creating a view model combining orders and `shirtQuantities` and calling it in the view:

```
public class ShirtOrdersViewModel
{
    public int ShirtSizeId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ShirtSize> ShirtSizes { get; set; }
    public int ShirtQuantityId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ShirtQuantity> ShirtQuantities { get; set; }
    public int ShirtId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Shirt> Shirts { get; set; }
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<File> Files { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

and this also does not work.

Comment: why don't you simply store the quantity in a numeric field  ? `int` ?

Comment: @Shyju I could do this but what about the existing orders?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Your model has a single `ShirtQuantity_Id` reference, so why would there be multiple `ShirtQuantity` objects in the `Order`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Even so should it not display with the reference to the ViewModel i created?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Does your `Order` actually have multiple `ShirtQuantity` objects that you're not modeling? Or is there a separate list of `ShirtQuantity` objects you want to use as a dropdown list? Please [edit] your question to provide more context.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I apologize for the confusion. I have already created a dropdown for the quantity. I am asking how to display the shirt quantity a user has already entered in the database using my current configuration

Comment: Well, it should be as simple as binding the dropdown to Order.ShirtQuantity.Id, but you're not really showing enough information for me to answer.

Comment: I fixed it by adding the quantity and size field to the table as int and string